# How to detect outliers in randomForest regression models?

Tags: r, outliers, random-forest

The randomForest package in R software includes outlier function for the detection of outliers. This function uses proximity matrix or randomForest object for the outlier detection. The manual says that the type of the randomForest object can not be regression? Why is it so that this function can be used for classification models only? Is there a reasonable way to detect outliers in regression models?

Comment: Here is a method that I developed for Random Forest Regression to Detect Outliers: http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2010/12/05/bioinformatics.btq628

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic idea behind this outlier score is how far an object is from a centroid of its predicted class, thus it makes little sense for regression.
Yet you can still produce proximity from regression RF by putting `proximity=TRUE` argument to the call to `randomForest` and then force outlier detection on it by calling `outlier(<rf object>$proximity)`, but this will only make assumption that all objects are from one class.

A bit less hopeless idea is to just convert regression problem to classification by splitting continuous decision into several intervals with `cut` or `Hmisc::cut2` and doing outlier detection on this -- but I have never tried it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that the outlier score is relative to the cluster centroids. I had impression that this was relative to other compounds. Now this restriction makes sense. I'll try to experiment with your other suggestions.